# POST response caching does not work in nginx

Tags: nginx, caching, http-post, nginx-location, nginx-cache

My task is to implement microcaching strategy using nginx, that is, cache responses of some POST endpoints for a few seconds.

In `http` section of the `nginx.conf` I have the following:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache keys_zone=cache:10m levels=1:2 inactive=600s max_size=100m;
```

Then I have `location` in `server`:

```
    location /my-url/ {
      root dir;
      client_max_body_size 50k;
      proxy_cache cache;
      proxy_cache_valid 10s;
      proxy_cache_methods POST;
      proxy_cache_key "$request_uri|$request_body";
      proxy_ignore_headers Vary;

      add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

      proxy_pass http://my-upstream;
    }
```

The application located at `my-upstream` outputs `Cache-Control: max-age=10` which, if I understand correctly, should make the responses cacheable.

But when I make repetitive requests using curl in short time (less than 10 seconds)

```
curl -v --data "a=b&c=d" https://my-host/my-url/1573
```

all of them reach the backend (according to backend logs). Also, `X-Cached` is always `MISS`.

Request and response follow:

```
> POST /my-url/1573 HTTP/1.1
> Host: my-host
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 113
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 113 out of 113 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 08 May 2018 07:16:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=60
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-XSS-Protection: 1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Cache-Control: max-age=10
< Content-Language: en-US
< X-Cached: MISS
```

So the caching does not work.

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Is there any logging facility in nginx that would allow to see why it chooses not to cache a response?

Comment: Do you have to use nginx for cache? you can try nuster, https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster, easily achieve your requirements

Comment: @nustercacheserver thank you, I'll consider nuster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that the following directive (which was defined globally) prevented caching from working:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

When I override it under `location` config with `proxy_buffering on;`, caching starts working.

So, to make caching work with POST requests, we have to do the following:

1. Output `Cache-Control: public, max-age=10` header on the server
2. Add `proxy_cache_path` config and `location` config in nginx (examples are given in the question text)
3. Make sure that `proxy_buffering` is `on` for the location on which we want to have caching enabled.

Comment: This answer, together with the question, not only solves the original problem, but serves as a concise tutorial for setting up nginx POST caching.  You saved me from a considerable amount of trial and error.  Well asked and well answered.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Roman Puchkovskiy's answer above - my origin server was returning the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
```

I configured my server to return this instead:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
```

And now Nginx behaves as expected ✅

I first tried adding this directive to my `nginx.conf`:

```
...
location /blah {
  ...
  proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
}
```

But it looks like that directive doesn't work the way I thought it would.

Note that I wasn't required to add `proxy_buffering on` to my `nginx.conf` so it seems I wasn't affected by that issue.